# Catch window events with JNA on Windows OS

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I'm trying to catch window open and close events with JNA. My goal is to get window title. It should be possible by installing WH_CBT hook by calling [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx%20SetWindowsHookEx) from User32 lib. The callback function for this hook is [CBTProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977(v=vs.85).aspx).

There is [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) library that doesn't support WH_CBT hook by default and I wrote my own implementation but it doesn't work. I double checked signature for CBTProc procedure and it's looks correct but it doesn't invoke.

Am I miss something?

Here is the code.

```
public class CbtProcHook {
private static volatile boolean quit;
private static HHOOK hhk;
private static WinUser.HOOKPROC sysCmdHook;

interface CbtProc extends WinUser.HOOKPROC {
    WinDef.LRESULT callback(int nCode, WinDef.WPARAM wParam, WinDef.LPARAM lParam);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final User32 lib = User32.INSTANCE;

    HMODULE hMod = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetModuleHandle(null);

    sysCmdHook = (CbtProc) (nCode, wParam, lParam) -> {
        System.out.println("in callback. nCode=" + nCode + " wParam.intValue=" + wParam.intValue());
        quit = true;
        return lib.CallNextHookEx(hhk, 1, wParam, null);
    };

    //        5 = WH_CBT
    hhk = lib.SetWindowsHookEx(5, sysCmdHook, hMod, 0);
    System.out.println("hook installed");

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (!quit) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    int error = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError();
                    if (error < 0) {
                        System.out.println("error=" + error);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.err.println("unhook and exit");
            lib.UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhk);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }.start();
```

}

Comment: You'll only be able to catch events within the current process.  Hooking events for all processes requires a DLL-based callback proc, which JNA does not fully support (you'd need to have some DLL-based code which instantiates a JVM within any given process).

Comment: Sry for a bit late reply but I'm not sure that you are right. This example was build on top of the another one with catching keyboard events. [That](https://java.net/projects/jna/sources/svn/content/trunk/jnalib/contrib/w32keyhook/KeyHook.java) example perfectly works outside of the application and can catch button press event everywhere in the system.

Comment: Low-level keyboard and mouse hooks do not have the same requirements for where the callback code resides.

Comment: Understood. Looks like there is no chance to catch windows event. Try to solve my task another way. Thank you man

Answer (score 0):

why have you replaced `nCode` by `1` and `lParam` by `NULL`?
also if `nCode` is less then zero you have to return the result of CallNextHookEx without further processing

```
sysCmdHook = (CbtProc) (nCode, wParam, lParam) -> {

    if(nCode<0)
          return lib.CallNextHookEx(hhk, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    System.out.println("in callback. nCode=" + nCode + " wParam.intValue=" + wParam.intValue());
    quit = true;
    return 0;
};
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The return type of CBTProc should be LRESULT. In your case the lambda return 0. It will not work. What are you trying to say with this piece of code?

Comment: @Mirian i am C developper, not java. but it is clear that you are not processing the hook as it would be. if ncode is less then 0 then you have nothing to do but return the result of CallNextHook with the exact parameters. i even moved println down after that.

Comment: @Mirian check the msdn link.

Comment: Thanks for youe reply. I understood your point. Unfortunately nothing works even after your changes. The sysCmdHook was never called. I'll read msdn again more thoroughly.